# Microcontroller not blinking LED

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, microchip, programming, assembly

I want to check if my microcontroller is working. It's the first time I'm working with microcontrollers. I followed [this](https://mlg556.github.io/8051%20assembly/2019/02/14/8051-assembly-workflow-in-macos.html) tutorial to blink a LED at the P1.0 pin, but nothing is happening.

My microcontroller is [AT89S51](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc2487.pdf). My operating system is macOS Ventura. I'm using Arduino Leonardo as an ISP programmer. Using BC548 transistor.

My Assembly code:

```
; Blink an LED connected to Pin P1.0 every second

        ORG 0H

        ; set P1.0 as output
        MOV     P1, #00000001B

LOOP:   ; turn on LED
        SETB    P1.0
        ; delay for 500ms
        ACALL   DELAY
        ; turn off LED
        CLR     P1.0
        ; delay for 500ms
        ACALL   DELAY
        ; jump back to the beginning of the loop
        JMP     LOOP

DELAY:  ; delay for 500ms
        MOV     R1, #10
        MOV     R2, #200
DELAY_LOOP:
        DJNZ    R1, $
        DJNZ    R2, DELAY_LOOP
        RET

        END
```

Creating .hex file:

```
@~ : c51asm blink.asm
C51ASM: advanced C51 macro assembler Version 1.2 (06 May 2011)
Copyright (C) 2011 Atmel Corp.


Pass 1 completed with no warnings and no errors

Pass 2 completed with no warnings and no errors

Segment usage:
   Code      :     22 bytes
   Data      :      0 bytes
   Idata     :      0 bytes
   Edata     :      0 bytes
   Fdata     :      0 bytes
   Xdata     :      0 bytes
   Bit       :      0 bits

   Register banks used: ---

   Warnings: 0
   Errors:   0
```

Writing into the microcontroller flash memory, where the file F40R96CIUSLFZFP.conf is defined [here](https://mlg556.github.io/downloads/2019-02-14-8051-assembly-workflow-in-macos/F40R96CIUSLFZFP.conf):

```
@~ : avrdude -C ~/micro/F40R96CIUSLFZFP.conf -c stk500v1 -P /dev/cu.usbmodem1101 -p 89s51 -b 19200 -U flash:w:/Users/me/blink.hex
```

Output:

```
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e5106 (probably 89s51)
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "/Users/me/blink.hex"
avrdude: input file /Users/me/blink.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (68 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.14s

avrdude: 68 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against /Users/me/blink.hex:
avrdude: input file /Users/me/blink.hex auto detected as Intel Hex

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.05s

avrdude: 68 bytes of flash verified

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Everything seems to be fine, but nothing happens (LED is not blinking). I don't know if I'm supposed to connect or disconnect something after the upload, but I guess it should start blinking right away(?). My connection images are below (although I've triple-checked).

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's impossible to see how the LED is connected and where, to see if there are any mistakes.

Comment: @Justme added another photo that clears the LED/transistor connection. The base of the transistor is connected to the P1.0 through a 1k ohm resistor to open/close the connection between emitter and collector making the LED connect from +5V to ground through a 220ohm resistor

Comment: Don't know which transistor it is, but it's possible the emitter and collector (two opposite pins) are reversed. Also, you could try a higher value resistor (like 10kΩ) directly to LED to see if your MCU is outputting anything.

Comment: @EdinFifić I now disconnected the transistor and wired the LED directly from the microcontroller pin through a resistor to GND. a voltage is detected at that pin (using a multimeter) but no current seems to be passing by

Comment: What voltages you measure? Is the LED inserted in correct orientation (anode and cathode)?

Comment: Just try moving LED to the opposite power rail (to ground instead of V+).

Comment: @Justme You're right, LED seems to be reversed.

Comment: @EdinFifić I could almost swear that I tried both ways, but you are right! The LED is now lighting up! Should I delete this question since the problem has nothing to do with the microcontroller and it was just a mistake in the LED polarity?

Comment: @ludicrous No, I don't think you should delete the question, but I would leave that up to the moderators. The point of SE is to share problems and solutions, and yours is a good example too. It shows how much we can go into details while it can be completely something else and just a simple mistake which makes it seem to not work after all the time, effort and knowledge invested.

Comment: @ludicrous For future reference, just remember that the LEDs with leads usually have anode (positive end) on the longer lead, and you can always test them before inserting them into a circuit, to make sure. I know I do. The old adage "measure twice, cut once" is very helpful and can save us from a lot of wasted time, money and headaches.

Comment: Just write your result up as an answer, it is perfectly fine to write an answer to your own question. And saying: the code is fine but I wired my circuit wrong (please describe with some detail) is also helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful to me and will certainly allow me to not make this mistake again.

Comment: @ludicrous - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "[áccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" your choice of the best answer { i.e. click the "tick mark" next to an answer to make it green - either [your answer](/help/self-answer) (can be áccepted after 2023-04-20 @ 13.05 UTC i.e. 48 hrs after the question was asked) or another one, if one is written (can be accepted any time) }. This shows that you don't need more help & future readers can quickly see the confirmed solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**: Turns out that my microcontroller is working and the code is fine. The issue has to do with the circuit itself, I overlooked the fact that the LED is in reverse bias - so, of course, no current was passing through.

Comment: Hint: The larger metal part inside the LED, holding the LED chip, is the cathode except it is an infrared LED.